# Getting Month and Year from date

Tags: php, date

I have a problem getting the year and month from the date given. I have this date 201911.. when i use

```
date('F Y',strtotime(201911))..
```

it shows Oct-19. It should be Nov-19

Comment: strtotime doesn't know if the 11 is the day or month, just add 01 to the end of it.  `date('F Y', strtotime('20191101'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do better to use [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Ym', 201911);
echo $date->format('F Y');
```

Output:

```
November 2019
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gUJIR)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just put ' around your String

```
echo date('F Y',strtotime('2019-11'));
```

Echo: November 2019

Comment: Also requires the dash, not just `(string)201911`

Answer (score 0):

All of another responses are ok!. the problem is that you dont tell to php what is the format of the date that you need trasform.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', 201911)->format('F Y');
```